# Does Cell Portal restart the run?

Tags: android-netrunner

Cell Portal has the following text:

> The Runner approaches the outermost piece of ice protecting the attacked server. Derez Cell Portal.

What happens after the Runner passes the outermost piece of ice: does it

1. Continue to the next ice after the outermost piece; or
2. Continue to the next ice after Cell Portal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the subroutine on Cell Portal fires, the Runner must encounter **all** ice (again), starting from the outermost.

Just be careful with terminology; the run doesn't "restart" (i.e. no "start of run" effects are fired again), the Runner is just teleported back to the first piece of ice and must continue from there.

Comment: I would love to think this is the case; it seems reasonable and fit to the cost of Cell Portal. But how do you deduce that?

Comment: Another caveat to using the word restart - Cards like [Komainu](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/05017) still have the subs they gained during the first run past them, sending a runner via cell portal through komainu a few times can flatline a runner with the wrong tech easily, particularly if you use Labyrinthine Servers or Whirlpool to keep them in the run.